# How to redirect Assemblies Versions in u-sql projects?

Tags: u-sql

In my u-sql script I'm using the JsonExtractor that have a reference to *"Newtonsoft.Json"*, in this script I also use a Custom Processor that uses *"Newtonsoft.Json"* too.

The problem is that the version used in the Processor is different from the version used by the JsonExtractor and it fails when load de dependencies of *"Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor"*.

Is there a way to redirect assemblies?

Comment: Have you tried uploading each version of the assembly  under a different name?

Comment: Did you try the alias solution referred below? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each U-SQL database can only contain one version of any given assembly. For example, if you need both version 7 and version 8 of the NewtonSoft Json.Net library, you need to register them in two different databases. Furthermore, each script can only refer to one version of a given assembly DLL. In this respect, U-SQL follows the C# assembly management and versioning semantics.

You can find more info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide#requirements

Answer (score 0):

In your custom processor just declare an alias for your version, and then you can use multiple dependencies by version. [Is it possible to reference different version of the same assembly into a single project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315589/is-it-possible-to-reference-different-version-of-the-same-assembly-into-a-single)