# Is there a way to use 2 different versions of a third-party library in separate class libraries included in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, assembly-binding-redirect

I have two separate class libraries: `A` and `B`.

Each class library references a third party library ([Mapsui](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui)), but `A` references a different version than `B`. I have exported the third party library DLLs to two separate folders, one for each version. At runtime in my main WPF project, I attempt to load in each class library as a plugin.

`B` works as expected since it references the newer version of the third party library but attempting to load `A` crashes with a `MethodNotFound` exception. The newer version of the third party library no longer contains the method that I call in class library `A`, which is why I get this error.

I have attempted everything mentioned in a similar thread ([Using multiple versions of the same DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll)) and have been unable to avoid this exception.

I am wondering if there is anyway for my class library to essentially hide it's internal references from my main project that loads it so that I don't run into issues with DLLs and namespaces having the same names but different versions.

How could I go about solving this problem?

Comment: If the [AppDomain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5916866/14956277) and [project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50262213/14956277) based answers did not work for you, please provide more information about your project and its structure. Some good examples would be your linked assemblies, build configuration, file structure, etc...

Comment: Here's another helpful HowTo concerning this problem:
https://www.learningsomethingnew.com/how-to-use-two-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-the-same-project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315589/is-it-possible-to-reference-different-version-of-the-same-assembly-into-a-single